# detect property display from no display to display block

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect when an elements display property has changed. Initially the element has no display property. I want to alert when the element has changed. I've tried the following the code, but nothing alerts.

```
document.getElementById('xxx').addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(e){
  if (e.attrName === 'style') {
    if (e.newValue === 'block') {
      alert('test!');
    }
  }
}, false);

setTimeout(function () {
  var xxx = document.getElementById('xxx');
  xxx.style.display = 'block';
  console.log(xxx);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also, do you really need to track that? This kind of thing is expensive. But if you really need to do it, try [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) instead. The "mutation events" you're using are deprecated. And both mutation "events" and "observer" apis have browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @bfavaretto I am working with chrome. This is the only method I am aware of to check for this sort of thing. If you have a better solution I wouldn't mind exploring it.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events): "WebKit doesn't support DOMAttrModified (see [webkit bug 8191](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8191) and [the workaround](http://about.silkapp.com/page/Mutation%20Events:%20What%20Happen))"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a practical example showing off how [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) can be used. Do note that I used the WebKit prefixed MutationObserver implementation, but you mentioned you're using Chrome anyway, so you can at least test this and if necessary adapt it to your needs.

First we create the `MutationObserver` and provide it with a callback. This callback will be called with 2 parameters - an array of `MutationRecord` instances, and secondly an instance of `MutationObserver` (the one which was responsible for the callback being called). This is useful when attaching a single callback to multiple MutationObservers. Note that it receives an array of MutationRecords rather than being called once for every MutationRecord. This allows bundling them up, which was necessary to improve performance.

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log(mutations);
});
```

Now we create (an optional) config object, to specify what type of mutations we're interested in. In this case, mutations of an attributes.

```
var config = { attributes: true };
```

Note that, although we define it here as a simple object, this will actually be used as a [MutationObserverInit object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit).

Now, finally, we tell the observer to observe a node:

```
observer.observe(document.getElementById('xxx'), config);
```

In case you're interested, I adapted your example into a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5mFM/1/).